# Residues of the function $\exp\big(\frac{2z}{z^2-1}\big)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am trying to calculate the residues of the following analytic function:
$$
f(z)=\exp\Big(\frac{2z}{z^2-1}\Big).
$$
Given that $z=\pm1$ are simple poles for the exponent, and given that the related function $\exp(1/z)$ has an essential singularity in the simple pole of the exponent, I think that I can deduce that the given function has two essential singularities in $z=\pm1$.
Is this reasoning correct?
Anyway, the following limit is indeterminate for any positive $n$
$$
\lim_{z\to1}(z-1)^nf(z),
$$
and this should be enough to say that $z=1$ is an essential singularity, and the same holds for $z=-1$.

Moreover, it is not difficult to find the residue at infinite, where the function is analytic, and I find
$$
R[\infty]=-\lim_{z\to\infty} z\big(f(z)-f(\infty)\big)=-2,
$$
where
$$
f(\infty)\equiv \lim_{z\to\infty} f(z)=1.
$$

Anyway I cannot use the relation
$$
R[+1]+R[-1]+R[\infty]=0,\tag{1}
$$
because there are two residues that I don't know yet.

I am not able to use known series expansions to determine the missing residues, nor I am able to use the definition of the residue as an integral.

This definition by the integral can be used to perform a numerical calculation, for which I obtain
$$
R[+1] = 1.479679824344824\\
R[-1] = 0.520320175655173
$$
and these values confirm the validity of $(1)$.

My question is: there is a way to determine the residues in the two essential singularities in a closed form by exact calculations?

Comment: In general, there is no "nice" way to determine the residue of any arbitrary essential singularity. Numerical methods involving the Cauchy Integral formula can be used, or if the Laurent series is rather obvious one can use that.

Comment: The first part is correct: essential singularities at $z = \pm 1$.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you

Comment: Why not try Taylor's series expansion, as

$$e^\frac{2z}{z^2-1} = 1 +\frac{2z}{z^2-1} + \frac{(\frac{2z}{z^2-1})^2}{2!} +..........$$

Now look for coefficient of simple poles $z-1 ,z+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account the simple fractions decomposition
$$
\frac{2z}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{1}{z+1}
$$
we have
$$
f(z)=\exp\Big(\frac{1}{z-1}\Big)\exp\Big(\frac{1}{z+1}\Big).
$$
Setting $w=z-1,$ we can study the following function around $w=0$
\begin{align}
g(w)&=\exp\Big(\frac{1}{w}\Big)\exp\Big(\frac{1}{w+2}\Big)=\\
  &=\Big(1+\frac{1}{w}+\frac{1}{2w^2}+\frac{1}{3!w^3}+\ldots\Big)\Big(a_0+a_1w+\frac{a_2}{2}w^2+\frac{a_3}{3!}w^3+\ldots\Big)
\end{align}
where the $a_n$ are the derivatives of $\exp[1/(w+2)]$ in $0$.

The residue is the coefficient of the term $1/w$, and this is
$$
R[1,f]=R[0,g]=a_0+\frac{a_1}{2}+\frac{a_2}{2\cdot3!}+\frac{a_3}{3!\cdot4!}+\ldots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n!(n+1)!}\tag1
$$
The coefficients $a_n$ are of the form
$$
a_n=b_n\cdot\frac{\sqrt{e}}{(-4)^n}
$$
with the first few $b_n$ given by
$$
1, 1, 5, 37, 361, 4361, 62701,\ldots
$$
that substituted into $(1)$ provide the approximation $1.4796803093686572,$ that could be improved taking more terms.

In the same manner can be evaluate the residue in $z=-1.$

Comment: $$
a_n  = ( - 1)^n\sqrt {\rm e}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{n!}{{k!}}\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}\frac{1}{{2^{n + k} }}} 
$$

Comment: @Gary how did you get this, other than OEIS?

Comment: Just from OEIS. :-)